# Angular service NOT hiting Asp.Net MVC Post Controller

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have this method in my angular service I want it to hit a the controller in my asp.net CORE api. But it does not hit my controller. I have tried to make the post in Postman and it works. I do not understand why my post in Angular does not work Thank you for your help.

```
  addFamily(family: Family) {

    this.http.post<Family>('https://localhost:44344/api/componentFamily', JSON.stringify(family))
  }
```

Here is my ASP.NET CORE API.

```
    // POST api/componentFamily
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ComponenFamilyViewModel componentFamilyViewModel)
    {
        Family family = new Family();
        family.FamilyId = componentFamilyViewModel.FamilyId;
        family.FamilyName = componentFamilyViewModel.FamilyName;

        await _componentFamilyService.AddFamily(family);

        return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = family.FamilyId }, family);
    }
```

Comment: did you add cors service in your startup.cs file?

Comment: @PritomSarkar I have  services.AddCors(); and             app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());  In my startup.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http client's observables are so called `cold`. In order for them to fire - and perform the web request - you have to subscribe to it, so

```
addFamily(family: Family) {

    return this.http.post<Family>('https://localhost:44344/api/componentFamily', JSON.stringify(family))
  }
```

and the caller

```
yourService.addFamily(famili).subscribe(result=>do whatever with the result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the object without stringify if you use [FromBody]:

```js
    this.http.post<Family>('https://localhost:44344/api/componentFamily', family)
```

Comment: It did not fix my problem, but you are right I do not need to and the JSON.stringify(family) in this case thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's HTTP client uses `RxJS` if you don't:

1. Call `.subscribe()` (or with a callback)
2. Call `toPromise().then(val => {...})`
3. Use the `async` pipe from a template like so: `<div *ngIf="response$ | async">`

...the side-effect (network call) will not be performed.

Try the following:

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public async onAddFamily(family: Family) {
     const response$ = this.http.post<Family>('https://localhost:44344/api/componentFamily', JSON.stringify(family))
     await response$.toPromise()
  }
```